# Will Socket.Receive(byte[]) return exactly one UDP packet?

Tags: .net, sockets, udp

I have such socket:

```
s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

Am I correct then when I call

```
s.Receive(byte[]);
```

I receive exactly one datagram? I need to process datagrams one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return *at most one* UDP packet. (If one consider that an Exception results in "not returning anything".)

The [Socket.Recieve documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx) states (in the remarks section):

> If you are using a connectionless Socket, **Receive will read the *first* queued datagram from the destination address** you specify in the Connect method.

However, note the following sentence:

> If the datagram you receive is larger than the size of the buffer parameter, buffer gets filled with the first part of the message, the excess data is lost and a SocketException is thrown.

The call may also throw an Exception on a timeout or when there is no data available in non-blocking mode, etc.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will. The specific feature of UDP that makes this possible is known as `Message Boundary Preservation.`

If by `one by one` you mean, *reliably* and *in order*, you must bear in mind that UDP does not guarantee either. Please refer [this](http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharp-network/IP-Programming-Basics/Programming-with-TCP-and-UDP/) article for further information